# Prevent program crashing when invalid coordinates are entered

Tags: python

Here are some relevant parts of the code. How would you go about fixing it so if a user enters the wrong coordinates which are out of the range, or even other characters/symbols, that the program prompts them for input again?

Here are the relevant parts of the program:

import random

```
def SetUpGameBoard(Board, Boardsize):
  for Row in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
    for Column in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
      if (Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 and Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1) or (Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 and Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1):
        Board[Row][Column] = "C"
      elif (Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1 and Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1) or (Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 and Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2):
        Board[Row][Column] = "H"
      else:
        Board[Row][Column] = " "

def ChangeBoardSize():
  BoardSize = int(input("Enter a board size (between 4 and 9): "))
  while not(BoardSize >= 4 and BoardSize <= 9):
    BoardSize = int(input("Enter a board size (between 4 and 9): "))
  return BoardSize

def CheckIfMoveIsValid(Board, Move):
  Row = Move % 10
  Column = Move // 10
  MoveIsValid = False
  if Board[Row][Column] == " ":
    MoveIsValid = True
  return MoveIsValid

def MakeMove(Board, BoardSize, Move, HumanPlayersTurn):
  Row = Move % 10
  Column = Move // 10
  if HumanPlayersTurn:
    Board[Row][Column] = "H"
  else:
    Board[Row][Column] = "C"
  FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, 1, 0)
  FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, -1, 0)
  FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, 0, 1)
  FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, 0, -1)
```

Many thanks for all the help. Here is the whole code if you wish to view it and run it:

http://www.writeurl.com/text/mpt643e0ryn96l0m8zhc/tpcx0mbjc8hdqo2zizwm/ettx0pq62ufshh3y2ays

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt?

Comment: It crashes. I have tried everything and it does not work.

Comment: Would help if you could provide the error message

Comment: I also recommend you to start your variables with a lower-case character. Upper-case is for classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you might run into a `ValueError` trying to convert strings to integers.
And since `ChangeBoardSize` is the only place where you process user input, a solution could be:

```
def ChangeBoardSize():
    try:
        BoardSize = int(input("Enter a board size (between 4 and 9): "))
        assert 4 <= BoardSize <= 9
        return BoardSize
    except:  # ValueError, AssertionError
        ChangeBoardSize()
```

And, as pointed out in the comments, you should stick to Python coding conventions (e.g. camel-case for functions, variables)

Comment: Apparently the `=<` is  invalid syntax.

Comment: It still throws an error saying `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: You should post where the Error is raised, which can be found in the stack trace